# Reordering items in two lists

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, list

Given list A with the following items{

```
var A = [A,B, [A,B,C],[A,B,C],[A,B,C,D],[A,B],A,B,C]
```

And list B with all the items in list A flattened:

```
var B = [A,B,A,B,C,A,B,C,A,B,C,D,A,B,A,B,C]
```

Note that the inner array in list B represent groups.

What is the most efficient way of re ordering an item in list A, which order should be reflected in list B.

For example, if the item B in the inner array in list A is moved before A, the lists should be updated as follows:

```
    var A = [A,B, [B,A,C],[A,B,C],[A,B,C,D],[A,B],A,B,C]
    var B = [A,B,B,A,C,A,B,C,A,B,C,D,A,B,A,B,C]
```

What have I tried so far:

Honestly, I am stuck! I have tried flattening list A and getting the corresponding item based off the index in list B, however, this does not work reliably. For example, it appear to work if there are two items in all the inner groups, however, with more than two items, it falls apart as the indexes do not match up. I sometimes get issues when the list is big as it might reference an index that has already been edited, and no, I have no control of the edits. My current attempt can be summed as:

```
B.indexOf(itemFromA) + indexFromA;
```

Comment: i suggest to order the original array and get a flat one later out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a recursive approach where you add all the elements from `list A` to `list B` one by one.

```
//list = list that should be represented in B
//newList = [];
function sortList(list,newList) {
    for(var elem of list) {
        if (typeof(elem) === "object") {
            sortList(elem,newList);
        } else {
        newList.push(elem);
        }
    }
    return newList;
}

B = sortList(A,[]);
```

Look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/apke67t2/) if this is what you want?

Comment: No, this is not helpful. Note that I want the arrays to be have the same ordering, and not a mere merge